# Gettind well-readable answer form modem (AT)

Tags: java, modem, at-command

I'm Java programmer. I try to get answer from my dial-up modem Acorp. Send AT-commands and see, that modem work correctly. I read answer using InputStream and I get this: `[B@127734f`
What is it? Why modem did'n send "`OK`"???.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may well have done - but it looks like you're just calling `toString()` on a byte array. Don't do that - if you want to convert the *contents* of a byte array to text, use a `String` constructor. For example:

```
String text = new String(data, 0, bytesRead, "US-ASCII");
```